# Using intermediate value theorem to prove the statement.

Tags: continuity, roots, solution-verification

prove the following statement:

> Assume $f(x)$ is continuous over $\left[-1,1\right]$ and $∀x∈\left[-1,1\right]$ 
>   :$\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\le1$, also assume $g(x)$ is continuous over $\left[-1,1\right]$ and $g(-1)=-
> 1$ , $g(1)=1$.
>
> Prove $$∃x_{0}∈\left[-1,1\right]:f\left(x_{0}\right)=g\left(x_{0}\right)$$

My try:

Define :
$$h\left(x\right):=f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)$$

Then $$h\left(1\right)=f\left(1\right)-g\left(1\right)=f\left(1\right)-1\le0$$

Also
$$h\left(-1\right)=f\left(-1\right)-g\left(-1\right)=f\left(-1\right)+1\ge0$$

Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous over $\left[-1,1\right]$, implies $h(x)$ is continuous over that 
interval, and since $h\left(-1\right)h\left(1\right)\le0$, using Intermediate value theorem implies

$$∃x_{0}∈\left[-1,1\right]:h\left(x_{0}\right)=0$$

Or equivalently $$∃x_{0}∈\left[-1,1\right]:f\left(x_{0}\right)=g\left(x_{0}\right)$$

Comment: That looks like a good proof to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be absolutely rigorous, I'd just highlight a few things.

If $h(1) = 0$ or $h(-1) = 0$, we are done.
Otherwise, we have $h(-1) > 0$ and $h(1) < 0$.
Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is some $x \in (-1, 1)$ with $h(x) = 0$.

Whatever the case, there is some $x\in[-1,1]$ with $h(x) = 0$, that is, with $f(x) = g(x)$.

---

What's important to highlight is that the intermediate value theorem grabs some $x$ strictly in between the endpoints, and that the value also lies strictly in between the value at the endpoints.